# VB.NET TreeView - dynamically selecting a node after it has been inserted or moved?

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I'm working on a VB.NET 2010 project which features a treeview control. The first thing I'm trying to figure out is how to insert a new node right after the currently selected node, and then make that newly inserted node the *selected* node. I can insert the new node no problem, but I can't figure out how to make it the "selected" node. The commented line below is the part I'm getting hung up on.

```
Private Sub AddNode_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddNode.Click

    If Not treeview1.SelectedNode Is Nothing Then
        treeview1.Nodes.Insert(treeview1.SelectedNode.Index + 1, TextBox1.Text)
        treeview.SelectedNode = treeview1.Nodes.Item(treeview1.SelectedNode.Index + 1) ' <-- I thought this would work, but it doesn't
    End If

End Sub
```

Secondly, I am using the below code to move a selected node up (in relation to other nodes). That works fine, but similar to the problem above, I can't figure out how to keep that node as the "selected" node after it has been moved.

```
Private Sub NodeUp_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NodeUp.Click

    Dim CurrentIndex As Integer = treeview1.SelectedNode.Index
    Dim CurrentNode As TreeNode = treeview1.SelectedNode
    treeview1.SelectedNode.Remove()
    treeview1.Nodes.Insert(CurrentIndex - 1, CurrentNode)

End Sub
```

This has to be simple, but I'm wracking my brain trying to figure out how, so I would appreciate a little bit of insight here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For setting the selected node in a `TreeView` you call [TreeView.SelectedNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx) to the `TreeNode` you want to select.

Now that we've established that, down to your examples:

When you call [TreeView.Nodes.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44bd832c.aspx) using the overload you have (integer, string) you actually get a `TreeNode` object returned to you.  So if you change your sample to

```
Private Sub AddNode_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddNode.Click

    If Not treeview1.SelectedNode Is Nothing Then
        Dim NewNode as TreeNode = treeview1.Nodes.Insert(treeview1.SelectedNode.Index + 1, TextBox1.Text)
        treeview.SelectedNode = NewNode
    End If

End Sub
```

then it should select the node you just created.

Your second example just needs to have one line added to it:

```
Private Sub NodeUp_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NodeUp.Click

    Dim CurrentIndex As Integer = treeview1.SelectedNode.Index
    Dim CurrentNode As TreeNode = treeview1.SelectedNode
    treeview1.SelectedNode.Remove()
    treeview1.Nodes.Insert(CurrentIndex - 1, CurrentNode)
    treeview1.SelectedNode = CurrentNode

End Sub
```

This is all working from brain compiler at the moment as I don't have access to Visual Studio to test it, so please let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, both solutions work perfectly! :) I feel kinda dumb now after seeing the answer to my 2nd example... major "doh!" moment, lol.

Comment: @NotQuiteThereYet It's no problem :D  This is how we learn -- we make mistakes, and see where we went wrong.  Believe me, I'm made sillier mistakes than this before.

Comment: Thank you! (Not a dumb question. I was trying to select the node from a reference instead of the TreeView... e.node.select)